# Nesting of query's not working

Tags: php, mysql

Am new here to php, i have written a code were i nested two queries i.e one query inside another but the problem is its showing me a unexpected '}' error of closing brace of second query, please help me.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","**","**","**");
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM status");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo '

                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="social-feed-box">' . 

                    $query = ("SELECT via FROM status WHERE IF(via='" . $_SESSION['via'] . "' ");
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {
                        '<div class="pull-right social-action dropdown">
                            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu m-t-xs">
                                <li><a href="post_delete.php">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>' .}.
                        '<div class="social-avatar">
                            <a href="" class="pull-left">' . 

                            '</a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a href="#">' 
                                    .$row['via'].
                                '</a>' . 
                                '<small class="text-muted">' .$row['created_at']. '</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social-body">' . 
                           '<p>' .$row['status']. '</p>

                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like this!</button>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social-footer">


                            <div class="social-comment">
                                <a href="" class="pull-left">' . 
                                    '<img alt="image" src="'.$_SESSION['doc'].'">' . 
                                '</a>

                                <div class="media-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write comment..."></textarea>
                                    </div>' . 
                                    '<div class="col-sm-1 form-group"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Post" align="left"></div>
                                </div>' . 
                                    '<div class="chat-message right">
                                        <div class="message">' . 
                                            '<a class="message-author" href="#">'  .$_SESSION['via']. '</a>' . 
                                            '<span class="message-date">' . '</span>
                                            <span class="message-content">
                                            Hello how are you?
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>';
                }
?>
```

Comment: Please specify the _exact_ error message and tell us what line that actually refers to (you did not post line numbers).

Comment: Sorry for that i mean error is specifically at <li><a href="post_delete.php">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>' .}. in above posted chunk code line no 24 or 25

Comment: error message is " unexpected '}'  "

Comment: Running a query inside a loop driven by a query is an anti-pattern. The only thing which could be worse would be to run a query in the loop which fetches the same data - it would appear that is exactly what you're code is doing. I would try to suggest a more sensible approach but the code you've provided is so odd I can't work out what it is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use any IDE like eclipse or sublime 
And two more points to keep in mind ...

1. Do everything in PHP by printing html tags with echo.

   `<?php 
        echo "<p>this p tag in php style</p>"; 
    ?>`
2. Mixture of HTML and PHP tag

   `<p>
     <?php 
       echo "this p tag is in partial PHP style"; 
    ?>
    </p>`;

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you sir, but sir can you please  resolve my actual issue.!

Answer (score 0):

The nested query is inside an echo. Try ending the echo and start a new one after the second query. Might be smart to use different variables for $row, but shouldn't matter.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "**", "**", "**");
$query = ("SELECT * FROM status");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="social-feed-box">';


$query = ("SELECT via FROM status WHERE IF(via='" . $_SESSION['via'] . "') ");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div class="pull-right social-action dropdown">
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn-white">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu m-t-xs">
                            <li><a href="post_delete.php">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>';
}
echo '<div class="social-avatar">
                        <a href="" class="pull-left"></a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <a href="#">'
. $row['via'] .
'</a>' .
'<small class="text-muted">' . $row['created_at'] . '</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-body">' .
'<p>' . $row['status'] . '</p>

                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like this!</button>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-footer">


                        <div class="social-comment">
                            <a href="" class="pull-left">' .
'<img alt="image" src="' . $_SESSION['doc'] . '">' .
'</a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write comment..."></textarea>
                                </div>' .
'<div class="col-sm-1 form-group"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Post" align="left"></div>
                            </div>' .
'<div class="chat-message right">
                                    <div class="message">' .
'<a class="message-author" href="#">' . $_SESSION['via'] . '</a>' .
'<span class="message-date">' . '</span>
                                        <span class="message-content">
                                        Hello how are you?
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks sir.!! your code is throwing an error "There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' found "  near ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo ' <div class="col-lg-12"> <div class="social-feed-box">'; $query = ("SELECT via FROM status WHERE IF(via='" . $_SESSION['via'] . "' "); $result = mysqli_query($con, $query); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()

Comment: I just copied your code. Didn't do a full check. Try updated code.

Answer (score 0):

@LordMarty is on the right path i think. You can write PHP in "echo" but it will ignore it and try to print it out. Try keeping your PHP (and your SQL query) out of any echoe's and HTML tags.

Maby try to close your PHP, continue with your HTML and then re-open your PHP again.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","**","**","**");
$query = ("SELECT * FROM status");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="social-feed-box">' . 
            <?php
                $query = ("SELECT via FROM status WHERE IF(via='" . $_SESSION['via'] . "' ");
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```